# grub saved default not working in bionic

Tags: boot, grub2

I have a  dual boot Debian stretch / Ubuntu bionic. Leading boot manager is the Debian one.

After Kernel update in bionic I start the bionic boot-loader for testing the new Kernel. There is also one mainline Kernel install in bionic.

but i will set the normal Ubuntu Kernel as default.

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=text
```

and `sudo grub-editenv list`:

```
saved_entry=gnulinux-advanced-0ddc8e0a-4b8a-479c-9502-5478ed3c4036>gnulinux-4.15.0-51-generic-advanced-0ddc8e0a-4b8a-479c-9502-5478ed3c4036
next_entry=
```

But after a reboot or shutdown + power on Ubuntu boots the mainline kernel. My menu entries are `grep -i "menuentry '" /boot/grub/grub.cfg|sed -r "s|--class .*$||g"|nl -v 0`:

```
 0  menuentry 'Ubuntu' 
 1      menuentry 'Ubuntu, mit Linux 4.20.17-042017-generic' 
 2      menuentry 'Ubuntu, mit Linux 4.20.17-042017-generic (recovery mode)' 
 3      menuentry 'Ubuntu, mit Linux 4.15.0-51-generic' 
 4      menuentry 'Ubuntu, mit Linux 4.15.0-51-generic (recovery mode)' 
 5      menuentry 'Ubuntu, mit Linux 4.15.0-50-generic' 
 6      menuentry 'Ubuntu, mit Linux 4.15.0-50-generic (recovery mode)' 
 7  menuentry 'Ubuntu text' 
 8      menuentry 'Ubuntu text, mit Linux 4.20.17-042017-generic' 
 9      menuentry 'Ubuntu text, mit Linux 4.15.0-51-generic' 
10      menuentry 'Ubuntu text, mit Linux 4.15.0-50-generic'
```

what is wrong with my configuration?

**Note:** I do run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: After editing `/etc/default/grub` you have to run `sudo update-grub` to make the changes take effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem sounds like this one: [GRUB 2 “stuck” on particular boot option](https://superuser.com/questions/695143/grub-2-stuck-on-particular-boot-option)

The solution in answers:

> In this case the next_entry field didn't get cleared after a reboot
>   like it should have (perhaps due to some btrfs incompatibility?)
>
> I was successfully able to unset it like this (again, within the
>   chroot):
>
> ```
> grub2-editenv /boot/grub2/grubenv unset next_entry
> ```
>
> After a reboot the grub menu was back to normal!